# VHDL code help- output once cycle earlier

Tags: delay, vhdl

In the following code i get output one cycle earlier. I am expecting a register to be formed for both pos_cnt and neg_cnt. The synthesis tool gives 2 counters with no registers. Why?

```
architecture rtl of divide_by_3 is
  signal pos_cnt :std_logic_vector (1 downto 0):="00";
  signal neg_cnt :std_logic_vector (1 downto 0):="00";
begin
  process (clk, reset) begin
      if (reset = '1') then
          pos_cnt <= (others=>'0');
      elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
          if (pos_cnt /= "01") then
              pos_cnt <= pos_cnt + 1;              
 else
    pos_cnt <= (others=>'0');
    end if;
      end if;
  end process;

  process (clk, reset) begin
      if (reset = '1') then
          neg_cnt <= (others=>'0');
      elsif (falling_edge(clk)) then
          if (neg_cnt /="01") then
             neg_cnt <= neg_cnt + 1; 
          else
    neg_cnt <= (others=>'0');
    end if;
      end if;
  end process;

  cout <= '1' when ((pos_cnt="01") and (neg_cnt ="01")) else
          '0';
```

end architecture;

Comment: [link](http://www.gstitt.ece.ufl.edu/vhdl/reg.vhd) check this link. Its says a signal assignement on rising edge results in register

Comment: A counter is practically just a register with math around it to increment, so what you're seeing seems correct. Could you explain the timing you were expecting in a little more detail?

Comment: I was expecting the answer to be more like this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h71ldylvvpkdku1/output.png). I use the following code [link](http://www.gstitt.ece.ufl.edu/vhdl/reg.vhd) and testbench [link](http://www.gstitt.ece.ufl.edu/vhdl/reg_tb.vhd) . The code here is a registers code where a signal is assigned at the rising edge clock. If you see the waveform( i have the link attached) the output is on the next rising clock edge.

Comment: Yes, in that case, the register is delayed by one clock cycle from the input. However, your code above doesn't have an input to "register". The value is still assigned on the clock edge, but it's assigned from the previous value + 1. So on the first clock edge out of reset, the counter increments. This is perfectly normal. If you want, you can add a clock/count enable, and then the output will change one clock after you assert the enable, maybe more like what you're expecting.

Comment: I still did not understand when a register is formed and when it is not. Can you please give me links to similar code 1) where a register is formed and 2) where register is not formed. And  tell me writing what code exactly will give out a register. Is there any link which explains clearly when a register is synthesized? Thanks a ton in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distinguishing between a register and a counter is a bit misleading. The only difference between your code and code that generates a standard register or flip-flop is that the input to your counter comes from the counter itself. If I take the liberty of removing the special wraparound case from your code, one of your counters becomes:

```
Count1 : process (clk, rst)
begin
  if rst = '1' then
    pos_cnt <= (others => '0');
  elsif rising_edge(clk) then
    pos_cnt <= pos_cnt + 1;
  end if;
end process Count1;
```

A basic register is:

```
Reg1 : process (clk, rst)
begin
  if rst = '1' then
    q <= (others => '0');
  elsif rising_edge(clk) then
    q <= d;
  end if;
end process Reg1;
```

`q` lags `d` by one clock cycle. Now, you could rewrite `Count1` as:

```
signal next_pos_cnt : ...

...

next_pos_cnt <= pos_cnt + 1;

Count2 : process (clk, rst)
begin
  if rst = '1' then
    pos_cnt <= (others => '0');
  elsif rising_edge(clk) then
    pos_cnt <= next_pos_cnt;
  end if;
end process Count2;
```

The function is identical to `Count1`, and you should recognize that the clocked process is virtually identical to `Reg1`. Both are registers. One just takes an external input, and the other has feedback.

So when you say that you expect the counter to behave like the register, you may just be missing the fact that the counter input is just a (combinational) function of *itself*. The counter's next value (assigned on the clock edge) lags behind its input by one clock cycle, just like the register. The only difference is where the input comes from. So, since its starting value is 0, on the first clock edge after reset, it becomes itself (0) + 1. Make sense? Where would the extra clock cycle delay be?

If there are any parts of this that you don't understand or that don't answer your question, please let me know.

**edit**: I meant to mention that you could add a clock enable for the counter if you wanted, like so:

```
...
elsif rising_edge(clk) then
  if clk_en = '1' then
    pos_cnt <= pos_cnt + 1;
  end if;
end if;
```

Then, the value of `pos_cnt` would change one clock after you asserted `clk_en`. Maybe that would be closer to the result you were expecting.